# Exibir o Form de uma DLL no Delphi DX10

Tags: delphi, dll

Estou com a seguinte situação: tenho um projeto, que chama uma *DLL* e esta possui um formulário. 
Até esse momento 'OK', realiza a chamada e exibe o formulário, só que uma coisa que me incomoda visualmente é que na bandeja do sistema fica duas aplicações abertas, uma do projeto e a outra da DLL.

Abrindo o formulário em `ShowModal`, e apertando *ctrl+tab* para o projeto, ele dá o foco mas não consigo acessar nada.

**Minha dúvida é como deixar somente em uma aplicação na bandeija do sistema.**

Codificação da DLL

```
library ChamadaForm;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Forms,
  Classes;

{$R *.res}

procedure exibir; stdcall;
var
 frm : TForm;
begin
  frm := TForm.Create(nil);
  frm.ShowModal;
  freeAndNil(frm);
end;

exports
  exibir;
begin
end.
```

Chamada da DLL no Projeto.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 exibir : procedure; stdcall;
 handle: THandle;
begin
  handle := LoadLibrary('ChamadaForm.dll');
  if Handle <> 0 then
  begin
    @exibir := GetProcAddress (Handle, 'exibir');
    if @exibir <> nil then
      exibir;
    FreeLibrary (Handle);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independente de você executar um `ShowModal` você deve lembrar que estamos executando uma segunda aplicação!

Existe outras formas de *Hookar* a aplicação dentro da outra!

Porém no **Delphi** para esse caso pode ser bem simples. Acesse o Source do projeto (da DLL no caso) e adicione essa Linha antes do `Application.Run`.

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := False;
```

Observe que o próprio nome do comando é bem intuitivo!

Comment: Olá @Júnior, nesse caso acredito que não funcionaria, pois não tem uma     appication.run a ***DLL*** é chamada no app principal.

Comment: Pressione `Ctrl+Alt+F11` será apresentado o *Project Manager*, então nele pressione  `Ctrl+V` (atalho para View Source).